# How does Soundcloud play audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundcloud

I'm pretty curious as to how SoundCloud plays audio on their site. I'm already aware of how they keep it playing during navigation, however, I have never seen how they actually get audio to play **at all**.

I was searching on their site for `<embed>`, `<object>`, `<audio>` and even `<bgsound>` tags. However, there are none to find.

This leads me to believe that they are either doing it via JavaScript (however, I still haven't found anything for that either) or through their backend (somehow).

If someone could give me some insight on how they do so, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Cheers.

Comment: Try reviewing `Resources` panel -> `Scripts` select files beginning with `"app"`, `"views"`

Comment: @guest271314 where?

Comment: At `DevTools` at home page of the site.